# Internal Error in codeblocks

Tags: c++, c, c++11, gcc, codeblocks

My code was compiling just fine until recently i started using a pair for stl maps and then their was some issue.

Every  time i compile any file which was compiling just fine before hand i get the error

***The same error comes for every file regardless of its function. Its some internal error.***
Ever time i try to compile a code this file stl_functions.h automatically opens.

```
c:\program files   (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|143|error: declaration of 'class _Tp'|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\include\c++\bits\stl_function.h|134|error:  shadows template parm 'class _Tp'|

||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
 ||=== Build finished: 50 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I got around 50 repetitive errors but i have shown only a few.
I have searched everywhere for this kind of error but i can't seem to find a solution.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How is anyone supposed to help without seeing the code?

Comment: Did you by chance try to edit a standard header ? Reinstall  MinGW/Code::Blocks and it should work again.

Comment: Okay i will reinstall to see if it works.

Comment: @tux3  can you just give me the file so that i don't have to reinstall the whole thing again.

Comment: @user3692108 I don't have it, I'm on Linux. Also, I don't know what version of MinGW you're using.

Comment: Thanks friend after re-installation the issue has been resolved, but not 100% how do i close this thread or accept your answer

Comment: I am new here so i don't know how

Comment: @user3692108 I turned my comment into an answer, you can accept it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you by chance try to edit a standard header ? Reinstall MinGW/Code::Blocks and it should work again.

Comment: If i click on the tick then that means the answer is accepted right?? Thanks for the help.